Metamsk error : while converting number to string, invalid number value ‘1e-7’, should be a number
I ma running a Daap the utilizes mostly metamask as a wallet and i do keep getting errors like this
while converting number to string, invalid number value ‘1e-7’, should be a number

this is a local metamask error that i don't know how it gets triggered, especially with that value that i don't have statically anywhere in my Daap code.
i use ethers.js to build the transaction and we use this psuedoflow :
contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer)
gasLimit = contract.estimateGas.transactionFunction(inputAddress, inputNumber)
await contract.transationFunction(inputAddress, inputNumber);

with inputNumber being a BigNumber object not a js number.
there is nothing special about the code itself, but the error still happens regularly.
I am using the latest ABI for my contract so that cannot be the source of the issue
EDIT : The error shows up on metamask but before the transaction is sent, i suppose it happens before the transaction signing.
The contract interaction is one of 2 transactions (i am not sure for personal reasons) :

The first transactions is an ERC20 increaseAllowance, so we are passing only an address and an amount
The second transaction is a contract interaction that would use the tokens that you allowed

in all transactions my Daap doesn't use or send that amount anywhere.

Where and when that error appears exactly? Can you share more about the app flow, the data you pass and when and where the error appears? Does the error appears before or after signing the transaction?

@GiuseppeBertone i added more description of my case, but a quick question for this error to appear it means metamask is trying to parse a number it gets from somewhere else, maybe when getting gasPrices? if so this might be an RPC issue.

What is most likely the case is that you are using a number in javascript.
Javascript can only handle 16 decimals, Ethereum uses 18 decimal.
This is why we turn them into BigInt aka BigNumbers.
You can use ethers parsing methods eg:
const initialSupply = ethers.parseUnits("1", 18);
const myBigInt = BigInt(initialSupply);

This will produce a valid bigInt number that you can pass as an argument to a contract.
EDIT
In vour case the number is inputNumber. If the number comes as a type number(JS) then you want to parse that into WEI with the propose methods.
You can validate the value of inputNumber by loggin it before and after parsing it to validate the type.
Note that your gas estimation must still be a valid transaction.

The issue is that i don't use pass that value anywhere, so i am not passing a wrong number instead of a bigNumber

Try passinginputNumber as an integer, either as string or bigNumber .
Solidity doesn't deal with decimals . So the contract you are interacting with can't have 1e-7 as an argument .
That's the only thing that I can think of without knowing your code or the contract you are interacting with .
EDIT: *BigNumber
